# jQuery SIMULTANEOUSLY animate all objects in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, animation, simultaneous

I am writing a script that does animations on a web-page.
In the process I need to add several elements to an array, and then simultaneously animate them.

Is it possible to use jQuery to SIMULTANEOUSLY animate all objects in an array? Or maybe there's a better method for that?

Thanx

Comment: jQuery does anything SIMULTANEOUSLY, if you ask it to. What problems are you having getting this to work?

Comment: I was looking for a method, and found some examples, but non-of them did it simultaneously, so i wanted to ask if its even possible, I am anew to jQuery an JS in general :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(ARRAY, function(index, value) { 
  // do amazing things such as:
  $(this).hide(200);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have several DOM elements in an array, all you need to do is slip them into a jQuery object, and do your animation.

```
$( arrayOfElements ).fadeOut();
```